# Is it bad practice to have mostly unused large sized column in mysql database table?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database table, which have more than 100 columns. I have to add two more columns, which if entered by user, keeps text data in it, but which is hardly used.

Now my question is, what will happen if I make it as `"medium text"` sized column and most of the user don't enter it. Will that column still takes the given memory, or only when user enters in to it,memory will be allocated.

I dont have much knowledge in this, So any explanations are welcome.  Also let me know if any other better method to go.

Answer (score 4):

It's not bad practice to use large texts or blobs even if it's not going to be used frequently, however try to use the smallest data type that suits your needs.

- TEXT requires N characters + 2 bytes
- MEDIUMTEXT requires N characters + 3 bytes
- LONGTEXT requires N characters + 4 bytes

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Additionally, if you allow them to be NULL (and assuming you are using InnoDB engine with COMPACT row format), it will only use 1 bit per column per row). So, if you have 2 NULLs, it will still use 1 byte.

Space Required for NULLs = **CEILING(N/8) bytes** where N is the number of NULL columns in a row.

More on: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html

On the other hand, having that many columns might not be ideal. Try restructuring your table into several tables.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to split that information in three tables. One contains general info about entry, one contains fields list and other holds relation between first and second table.

```
[Product]
ID | name | model | price

[Fields]
ID | field_name | field_key | is_mandatory

[Field_to_product]
field_id | product_id | value
```

And in `Field_to_product` you hold only these values, that product has.

**On update** delete all entries for that product from `Field_to_product` and rewrite it's values.

Comment: @DKSan No, with provided information and `I dont have much knowledge in this, So any explanations are welcome. Also let me know if any other better method to go.` I can only suggest that structure change.

Comment: Ok, i was just confused because there was nothing said about a procuct.

Comment: @DKSan Just as example

Answer (score 1):

If the length of data on the column used less than 65,535 characters, you should consider using varchar, rather than text type variant.

blob, text, varchar, and varbinary data type are pointer type. 
They only store 1-2 byte pointer header and for the data part will acquire space in dynamic manner. they alocate space  as the data fill in the column. the N part when creating type such as varchar(N) is for validation purpose.

Blob and binary differ from text and varchar in the way database engine use index for sorting and use matching algorithm to compare data. 
Where text based will be stored and compared using collation of character set. The way the database engine store the character in physical is defined by character set. Some character set like Japanese or Chinese, require double byte to store, while Latin character use single digit. And so on.
While Blob and binary data is saved as is and no reference to any character set.

Aside from data type, you should consider normalize the table.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

A table with 100 columns will hold performance down as the data row grow.
Make searching, inserting and updating the table take more time as it grow.

You can try sql utility syntax from sql query console to show your table status

```
show table status from your_table_name;
```

The actual size of table is not only defined by datatype, but also come from index(s), key(s). Index can define on set of column(s), so multiple index can be created on a single table. 
The space requirement will also grew exponential if using a text data type column with full text index enabled on that column.